# Использование псевдокласса first-child

Tags: html, css

```
<ul id="footer">
<li>
    <h2>Что это?</h2>
        <ul class="information" style="display:none;">
            <p>шшш!</p>
        </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <h2>А это что??!!!?</h2>
        <ul class="information" style="display:none;">
            <p>Тоже </p>
        </ul>   
</li>
<li>
    <h2>А это что?</h2>
        <ul class="information" style="display:none;">
            <p>Тоже !</p>
        </ul>   
</li>
</ul>
```

Есть такой элемент на странице. Как с помощью css найти все `<ul class="information" style="display:none;">`?

Пытался так:

```
#footer  li .information ul p:first-child   .information:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: -10px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #444;
```

}

Не получается. Да и по-другому тоже пробовал, тоже не получается.

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

А потому что вы выбираете `ul` внутри `.information`. Если вы хотите выбрать список, выбирайте его как `ul.information`. Далее, `p:first-child .information:after` - это вставка после `.information`, находящегося внутри `p:first-child`. Полагаю, это можно убрать. Или что вы хотите сделать? И на всякий случай: `tag:after{content:''}` IE поддерживает с 9 версии.

Comment: <code>#footer  ul.information  p:first-child   .information:after{.....}
</code>
 так?

Comment: Вы .information ищете внутри p. В коде это не описано, поэтому делаю вывод, что вы хотите вернуться к родительскому элементу. А это невозможно.

Comment: непонял. Мне нужно ul в li достать

Comment: А вы чего хотите-то?

Comment: Мне нужно добраться о тега ulкоторый находиться в теги li